# При вызове setValue затираются errors, которые были установлены на форме

Tags: typescript, angular2

Я зелёный в фронт разработке, поэтому вопрос:
Как можно установить значение формы  не затирая ошибки на форме?
Пример:

```
this.form.setErrors({ warning: 'ERROR'});
var imTrue = this.form.hasError('warning'); //true
this.form.setValue('AngularWTF', { emitEvent: false, onlySelf: true });
var imFalse = this.form.hasError('warning'); //false
```

Comment: Вызовите setValue до установки errors

Comment: A form control instance provides a setValue() method that updates the value of the form control and validates the structure of the value provided against the control's structure. https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: @AzizUmarov Эх, надеялся есть лазейки, как можно это обойти, пришлось ставить значения до установки errors.
Спасибо вам!